# Blank ADO.NET objects over WCF

Tags: wcf, ado.net, entity-framework-5

I'm trying to expose objects created from an ADO.NET object (created from a database).

When I try to return one of these objects from a service, all the object's fields are 0.

Here is the service contract:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace="http://www.thatindigogirl.com/samples/2006/06")]
public interface IMFileService
{
    [OperationContract]
    File GetFile();
}
```

Here is the type that implements the service contract:

```
public class MFileService : IMFileService
{
    public File GetFile()
    {
        using (FileEntities ctx = new FileEntities())
        {
            File aFile = (from f in ctx.Files
                          where f.ID == 5
                          select f).FirstOrDefault();       // No connection string named 'FileEntities' could be found in the application config file.
            return aFile;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my client code:

```
    EndpointAddress ep = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8000/MFileService/MFileService");

    IMFileService proxy = ChannelFactory<IMFileService>.CreateChannel(new BasicHttpBinding(), ep);
    File f = proxy.GetFile();
    Console.WriteLine("File info: " + f.Name + ", " + f.ID + ", " + f.ParentDirectory + ", " + f.Size);
    Console.ReadLine();
```

I'm not sure why fiddler doesn't see the request to the database, the response, or the message from the host to the client.

Is something like this even allowed with ADO.NET objects? Or do I have to create my own class and put the ADO.NET object data into it first before I send it over the wire?

Comment: If you have lazyloading enabled it will try to serialize the entity until all foreign keys are processed which in a large set will not work because of the restrictions in maxquota's in your client's web.config. It is also best to make your own class as a Model for your entity. Also check out the log with the SVC Trace listener: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Fiddler doesn't see anything going to localhost. You must use your real external IP address or computer name. Also if your comment in data retrieval code means exception you should first solve it by placing connection string into web.config.